# Undo a revert checkpoint on Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python-2.7, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I reverted to a previous checkpoint on jupyter notebook (from file --> revert to checkpoint in the menu). Is there a way to undo the revert and get back to the version I was on? I am not using git.

Comment: did you manage to get back to previous version?